# How to modify app script to use google form's "go to section based on answer"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using this app script below to create a multiple-choice quiz form from sheets.
I would like change it to use the "go to section based on answer" option from google form to make the quiz more interactive.
Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you

Here is the code that I have now:

```js
function popForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();

  // Read the sheet data into 3 arrays.  Would be better practice (faster performance) to read all into 1 array and divide as needed).  
  var myQuestions = sheet.getRange(1,1,numberRows,1).getValues();
  var myAnswers = sheet.getRange(1,2,numberRows,1).getValues();
  var myGuesses = sheet.getRange(1,2,numberRows,5).getValues();

  // Shuffle the 5 choices horizontally.  This script only works with Questions in col A, correct Answer in col B, and false choices in col C thru F.
  var myShuffled = myGuesses.map(shuffleEachRow);
  Logger.log(myShuffled);
  Logger.log(myAnswers);

  // Create the form as a quiz.  The resulting form's "Quiz options" are different from a manually created quiz.  Be aware (and change manually if needed!
  var form = FormApp.create('States and Capitals Quiz');
  form.setIsQuiz(true);

  // Write out each multiple choice question to the form.
  for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){
    if (myShuffled[i][0] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])
      ]);
    }
    else if (myShuffled[i][1] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])
      ]);
    }
    else if (myShuffled[i][2] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])
      ]);
    }
    else if (myShuffled[i][3] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4])
      ]);
    }
    else {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4],true)
      ]);
    }
  }
}

// This function, called by popForm, shuffles the 5 choices.
function shuffleEachRow(array) {
  var i, j, temp;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

How can I modify this in order to use the "go to section based on answer" option with the FormApp library?